# Is there a smallest possible sample size for MANOVA (post-hoc)

Tags: manova

I am testing two DV and two IV using a two-way MANOVA. I have four groups. I had used g*power to recommend a sample size, however I have not yet achieved this recommended sample size. Instead I have 11 samples from 11 random participants. I understand that this is not optimal because then I have uneven samples in groups (i.e. A=3, B=3, C=3, D=2) and DV's (DV1=6, DV2=5). However, that aside, my concern is whether there is a minimum sample size that is acceptable.

I have checked the significance of my results and found they are strongly significant. In RStudio the results are marked with three asterisk ****. Given that my alpha remains at 0.05 (in G*power the graphs show that) I have no chance to make a Type I error. By the low power of my sample size I have a very large chance to make a Type II error (to accept the null hypothesis even though it is false). My results show a significant difference despite this low power. So in this case I won't make a Type II error, as I will reject the null hypothesis.
I was wondering if this is an acceptable statistical result (so that results would be considered for publication), or whether there is a minimum sample size that should be reached. I heard there is a rule 'you need to have more cases in each cell than you have DVs'. I have two DVs. Does that mean I have covered the minimum requirements? I don't have a textbook or journal article to cite this rule either. I would appreciate if someone can help me out here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following reference. I would prefer Journal or Textbook references.

> "Assumption #4: You should have an adequate sample size. Although the larger your sample size, the better; for MANOVA, you need to have more cases in each group than the number of dependent variables you are analysing."

https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-manova-using-spss-statistics.php

Your feedback is much appreciated!

---

> "POWER AND SAMPLE SIZE:
> As we have seen, the first test that’s performed when we do a MANOVA is a test for homogeneity of the VCV matrices. For this test to run, we must have more subjects than variables in every cell (Tabachnick and Fidell, 1996)."

https://basicmedicalkey.com/multivariate-anova-manova/